# Query in command must target a single shard key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, spring-data-mongodb, sharding, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to insert multiple documents to Cosmos DB with Mongo Api which has a shard key as follows,

```
insertAll(trips.stream().map(t -> Document.parse(gson.toJson(t))).collect(Collectors.toList()),"trip");
```

insertAll method is as follows,

```
private void insertAll(List<Document> data, String collectionName) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName);
        collection.insertMany(data);
    }
```

And the documents I'm trying to insert are as follows,

```
Document{{sensorId=b827ebe942b7, liftId=1edb945b-29e7-c6c7-d20b-87c0, timestamp=1554902007838, ..............}}
```

Even though I'm providing the shard key which is `liftId` I get a exception saying single shard key must be provided.

```
Command failed with error 61: 'query in command must target a single shard key' on server cdb-ms-prod-southeastasia1-fd10.documents.azure.com:10255. 
    The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 61, "errmsg" : "query in command must target a single shard key", "$err" : "query in command must target a single shard key" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 61: 'query in command must target a single shard key' on server cdb-ms-...-fd10.documents.azure.com:someport. The full response is { "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 61, "errmsg" : "query in command must target a single shard key", "$err" : "query in command must target a single shard key" }
```

Any help to fix this? I'm using `spring data mongodb`

Comment: The "query in command must target a single shard key" error message is specific to CosmosDB's implementation of sharding/partitioning (which is very different from MongoDB's implementation). You haven't specified your Spring Data or Java driver versions, but a call to `insertMany` in the MongoDB driver is usually converted to a bulk write. This error message seems to suggest that bulk writes need to target a single shard. To test that theory you could try inserting a batch of documents which all have the same shard key (`liftId`) value.

Comment: Actual I'm trying with same liftId, and even tried with single insert as well. My spring data version is `spring-data-mongodb-2.0.9`

Comment: Did you try a single insert using `insertOne()` or `insertMany()`? If only the latter, perhaps Cosmos doesn't support bulk writes into partitioned collections. If neither works I'm out of guesses for the moment :)

Comment: yeah  I tried single insert, same error